# pipe/union operator in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, reducers

what is a better replacement for `lambda x, y: x | y` in form of `operator.x`

background:
I'm trying to form django queries dynamically, for which I have created something like `queries=[Q(**{query_key: phrase}) for query_key in query_keys]` where query_keys is dynamically gerarated list of string which represents django query e.g. `id__icontains`

Comment: For background for everyone else, Django does OR queries using q objects and pipes akin to `Q(...) | Q(...)` and the op wants to join their list together with pipes

Comment: I should have headed to https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html before stackoverflow.
`operator.or_` is working for me.

Comment: See the duplicate, there is also `Q.OR`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions, the function corresponding to the `|` operator is called `or_`.